# Гиперссылки как у iCloud Pages

Tags: javascript

Добрый день, как сделать гиперссылки как у iCloud Pages когда пишешь сайт и он сразу становится ссылкой как и в Google Docs.
Имеется div contenteditable="true". Подскажите как реализовать подобное?

Comment: Пример можно где то увидеть?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7jr886du/1/ нужно когда пишешь ссылку, даже без http слово сразу должно стать ей.